# How accept HTML in page/widget title ? (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, plugins, widget

I'm using wordpress and i would put HTML link in title page or title widget.

Thanks to help me :)

Comment: So what's stopping you from putting a link?

Comment: wordpress don't accept html in title :(

Comment: since the post title is already a link, you can't put one there. but if it's in the widget, that's part of the theme

Comment: Yes but in page title, i wanna put image but i can't.

Comment: can you show an example? The title of a post is always a link

Comment: Not, i wanna put link into title

Answer (score 0):

You can't put images in title tags. Not ever, not just in WordPress. If you are wanting an image to show up next to the URL in the browser window, that's called a favicon. Look that up and you'll find a number of generators and tutorials.

Or, are you trying to figure out how to put an image next to the heading tag? (such as `<h1>`)?